# Wifi failing after update to 10.15.5 - Macbook Pro 15 (2018)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I after an update to 10.15.5 or even 10.15.4, my WiFi has periodically been failing.

At first, I thought it could be my internet or access point.

At failure, I would test with my mobile phone on the same network using a speed test app. My mobile phone always had connectivity and faster speeds (about 40mbs)

I tried my iPad with the same results.

Internet would fail for 30-60 seconds then come back.

Finally, I have plugged directly into ethernet and I am consistently getting 180mbs

As a side note: I am running SONOS and it never drops. It is on WiFi.

I am using Google WiFi with 4 access points. I am getting a "Great" signal on all 4 WiFi access points.

Comment: Go to system Preferences > Network > WiFi tab and delete the WiFi network(s) that are troublesome and recreate them. Report back.

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the latest update. I have a MacBook Pro that’s used in the dining room that has direct line of sight to a Ubiquiti ceiling mounted WAP.  Up to last week it was rock solid stable.  Applied the update, and I’ve been in  tech support mode since. Luckily I did an APFS snapshot prior so I was able to roll back.  But it is an update issue and this is something  that drives me nuts about Apple.  They have a known, finite number of machines to test for, yet they hose critical things like WiFi up royally.